# Detect allowNetworking parameter in Flash

Tags: flash, security, sandbox

Greetings,

This is regarding a Flash security/sandbox issue. I was wondering if there was a way for the loaded Flash .swf object to know whether `allowNetworking="internal"` is set for it, possibly using ActionScript (2.0 or 3.0).

I found a [solution](http://jaycsantos.com/flash/experiment-how-to-determine-if-allownetworking-parameter-is-enabled/), but it does not differentiate whether the restrictions are from `allowNetworking` or `allowScriptAccess` settings.

I am not particularly looking for a work around (although that would be interesting too), but just to be able to **detect** whether specifically `allowNetworking` is set to `"internal"` or at least something other than `"all"`.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the networking API restrictions by trying to execute specific restricted APIs and seeing if a SecurityError is thrown.

```
public static function getNetworkingRestriction():String {

            var result:String = "all"; // default level

            try {
                // first try SharedObject.  If it throws a SecurityError, then allowNetworking="none"
                SharedObject.getLocal("test"); 

                try {
                    // SharedObject didn't throw a SecurityError. 
                    //If ExternalInterface.call() throws a SecurityError then allowNetworking="internal"
                    ExternalInterface.call(""); 
                }
                catch (e:SecurityError) {
                    result = "internal";
                }

            }
            catch (e:SecurityError) {
                result = "none";        
            }

            return result;

        }
```

A list of the restricted networking APIs can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000351.html#wp150192%20%22here%22.)

Comment: Thank you @colin-cochrane . However, the proposed method does not exclusively/reliably detect the `allowNetworking` setting as the behaviour is also influenced by the `allowScriptAccess` setting. Following are the results obtained with the method. `allowNetworking="all"` reliable only when `allowScriptAccess="always"` or if swf loaded from **same domain** with `allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"`.